# Why is String.length() a method?

Tags: java, string

If a String object is immutable (and thus obviously cannot change its length), why is `length()` a method, as opposed to simply being `public final int length` such as there is in an array?

Is it simply a getter method, or does it make some sort of calculation?

Just trying to see the logic behind this.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source and find out?

Comment: What benefit would obtain if it were a field? Conversely, why didn't you ask why arrays have a `length` field rather than a `length()` method?

Comment: The classes that date back to the early versions of the JDK don't show much consistency – Strings have a `length()` method, arrays have a field, Collections have `size()`, neither expose JavaBeans getters for these (while the DOM `NodeList` does.) I'd chalk this up to a design wart preserved for the sake of compatibility but can't really back the opinion with anything.

Comment: @erickson because for me it is obvious that a public field provides better performance than an accessor method. (at least before the method gets inlined, if at all) As far as I understand, there is no reason to create a getter on a `final` variable. (unless the getters does something more than simply returning the variable, which doesn't seem to be the case.)

Comment: @skaffman, that wouldn't necessarily explain the design decision. It's a good question, actually.  Perhaps you can take a look at the source code and explain why it's `length()` and not `length` - I don't see anything to indicate the "why".

Comment: @erickson Not violating conventions of the platform / programming paradigm would be one benefit. Methods (at least in Javaland) should be verbs, not nouns.

Comment: It can provide better performance, but in practice, it makes no difference. Direct field references break encapsulation, and are a bad design choice---especially when driven by unfounded beliefs about performance.

Comment: @Inerdial If a collection's size is not permanent, then I think it is obvious that a getter is required since the variable behind it will not be `final` and thus cannot be public.

Comment: @erickson so a getter method can never be slower than accessing a public member directly?

Comment: Can someone post a link to the String source code?

Comment: @Acidic do you want an answer/discussion or do you want to argue about nanoseconds?

Comment: @Acidic Most people would prefer having a consistent way of getting the number of elements from collection-like objects rather than trying to indicate (im)mutability by the choice of final field vs. getter. Anyway, what I was trying to say there might not be *any* reasonable explanation. JDK 1.0 was rough around the edges, and some of these just weren't ever smoothed over. There's a good chance the reason is "someone coded it this way and nobody bothered to change it".

Comment: @user949300 I simply want to understand the logic behind the decision of making `length()` a method. nanoseconds or not, writing MORE code for LESS perofrmance with NO benefits seems odd to me. Unless this is not the case - which is what I am trying to find out.

Comment: CharSequence is an example of why their decision was correct.

Comment: Hmm, how do you interpret, "It *can* provide better performance," as meaning that field access can't be faster than a getter?

Comment: @user949300 Unfortunately, I fail to understand the benefit of that.

Comment: The benefit is in usage, not performance. Libraries are written for the benefit of programmers.

Comment: @erickson I simply wish to make sure that I understand what you are saying; I am not trying to be aggressive, I am simply flabbergasted. Back to the subject, I still see no reason to create a basic getter for a `final` variable, when in similar situations (such as Arrays) a `public final` variable is indeed provided.

Comment: @Acidic The (after the fact) benefit is that you can have multiple implementations of a `CharSequence`. One of these is `StringBuffer`, which is obviously mutable, and couldn't use a field to expose its length. This lets you write code that can work with both `String` and `StringBuffer` instances transparently. While this isn't common, the Wicket framework uses this in its API.

Comment: @Acidic Arrays being "special" and requiring manual conversion to / from collections instead of at least partially implementing `List` (like .NET's arrays do) is, to me, a major annoyance in Java, and not something I'd hold up as a benefit.

Comment: @Inerdial I did not bring an array as an example to why it SHOULD be a member, simply as an example to an alternative within Java itself.

Comment: @erickson, Array *do not* have `length` field.

Comment: @Acidic, length() should be a function, `count` may not even exist and instead String can use the underlying array.length which would suffice most of the time. Presently, length() is the same as accessing the field directly once the JIT takes care. Morealso the JIT tends to generate even more optimized code (SSE instructions on x64). As a rule of the thumb fields should not be exposed since they bind the implementation and internal details of the latter. i.e. `length()` is a good decision but CharSequence that was introduced to help NIO's CharBuffer (1.4) is not a good support of the idea.

Comment: @bestsss According to *[The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#64347),* as well as the common knowledge of myriads of Java programmers, you are completely wrong. Java arrays have field `public final int length`.

Comment: @erickson, try this: `new int[0].getClass().getDeclaredField("length")` arrays do not have any fields. While accessed as field, the byte code OP is `ARRAYLENGTH`, not `GETFIELD`. `length` field does not have a reflective counter part and it's handled rather poorly by the spec. by being a syntax only.

Comment: @bestsss That is a good point, but I don't find it convincing; the specification is explicit in its language, language designers utilize the field terminology, etc. Obviously there are differences between an array and an `Object`, between a `Class` for an array and a `Class` for other objects. I'm more inclined to say that's simply an overlooked case in reflection. Anyway, can you explain your point? Is there a useful distinction?

Comment: @erickson, it's "overlooked" in JNI as well. Yes, there is a subtle distinction. There is no difference between Class objects of arrays and the rest objects. However, the field `length` just does not exists as normal field. It's a part of the object header where the value of `System.identityHashCode` is stored. So is `Class` reference. In JNI there is an extra function to get array length unlike using an offset for the rest of the fields. I admit `length` looks like a field in Java source code but outside the source it's not treated as field anywhere else.

Comment: ...continuing on the reflection part constructors are handled properly even being a method named `<init>`. The reflection code removes the declared `<init>` (and `<clinit>` - class initializers) methods in order to provide proper use as `java.lang.Constructor`.  Even constructors are declared as methods but invoked a bit differently (`INVOKESPECIAL`) the API designers felt obliged to provide proper interface. Arrays got a special class (java.lang.Array) w/ exclusively static methods to carry the length/new instance and so on, truly treated differently. I was a bit surprise of the length omissi

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Java is a standard, not just an implementation. Different vendors can license and implement Java differently, as long as they adhere to the standard. By making the standard call for a field, that limits the implementation quite severely, for no good reason.

Also a method is much more flexible in terms of the future of a class. It is almost never done, except in some very early Java classes, to expose a final constant as a field that can have a different value with each instance of the class, rather than as a method.

The `length()` method well [predates](http://www.tns.lcs.mit.edu/manuals/java-1.1.1/api/java.lang.String.html#length%28%29) the CharSequence interface, probably from its first version. Look how well that worked out. Years later, without any loss of backwards compatibility, the CharSequence interface was introduced and fit in nicely. This would not have been possible with a field.

So let's really inverse the question (which is what you should do when you design a class intended to remain unchanged for decades): What does a field gain here, why not simply make it a method?

Comment: That is an interesting thought. A field, for me, is less code with equivalent - or better performance.

Comment: With a tradeoff, of less encapsulation. It can't exist as part of an interface. (Interfaces have constants, but that isn't the same thing) and you can't change your mind about the field. Anyway, any supposed performance benefit is a premature optimization. http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth

Comment: "..you can't change your mind.." But if a `String` is immutable, what else can its number of characters be denoted by other than a `final` member?

Comment: Good point. If Strings ever wanted to become mutable objects, length() would ensure backwards compatibility, where a final member would complicate such an evolution.

Comment: @Acidic: Well, the String is a `char[]`, an offset, and a length, right? Couldn't it also be a `char[]`, an offset, and a last index? In that case, length would be `end - start`. As a user, you shouldn't care which approach they take, and as a maintainer, you'd want the flexibility of changing approaches down the line. Fields don't give you that, so you end up locked into an approach which may limit you down the line.

Comment: I don't want to sound like a broken record, but I see no reason to implement a method of calculating an accessible (to the `String` class itself) and constant value. I logically see no reason why a constant should ever be more than it is - a constant.

Comment: @Acidic The reason would be that you're uncomfortable specifying a property of an object to be immutable (not constant) for the entire future of your codebase. If you're absolutely certain that a given property will never need to change to a mutable one and are willing to commit to this via an irreversible design choice, go for it. Given how the immutability of Strings is a very important property that will never be changed, whoever originally designed their API could've chosen this option. For whichever reason, he did not, and this choice was later justified by the `CharSequence` interface.

Comment: @Acidic @Inerdial: Even then, don't go for it. Make an accessor method, if for no other reason than for consistency. Why should users of your library have to remember that such-and-such property is a field, but so-and-so is a method? If you want to retroactively add an interface (e.g. `CharSequence`), why make users wonder what's the difference between `length` and `length()`? You can't make all properties be fields, but you can make them all be methods, so just play by good OO rules and use accessor methods unless you have a really good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @Acidic, perhaps this will give you some further insight: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UniformAccessPrinciple.html

Comment: By the way, one advantage of calculating it vs. having a field store it is in an environment where memory is very constrained. Forcing that to be stored for every string, instead of calculated when needed (potentially much less often) may cause problems. I wouldn't worry about it, but as a standard, it forces the implementation into a corner to specify a field instead of a method.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fundamental tenet of encapsulation.

Part of encapsulation is that the class should hide its implementation from its interface (in the "design by contract" sense of an interface, not in the Java keyword sense).

What you want is the String's length -- you shouldn't care if this is cached, calculated, delegates to some other field, etc. If the JDK people want to change the implementation down the road, they should be able to do so without you having to recompile.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a `.length()` method was considered more consistent with the corresponding method for a `StringBuffer`, which would obviously need more than a `final` member variable.

The `String` class was probably one of the very first classes defined for Java, ever. It's possible (and this is just speculation) that the implementation used a `.length()` method before `final` member variables even existed. It wouldn't take very long before the use of the method was well-embedded into the body of Java code existing at the time.

Comment: Your original argument holds some water with `StringBuffer` in place of `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @erickson: Oh, right! It's been so long since I've used a `StringBuffer`... thanks.

Comment: That seems logical, though I would guess that `Array` was also one of the earliest classes in Java and yet it uses a field instead.

Comment: Arrays in Java are special, they're sort of classes but not really. You'll notice that arrays don't have any *methods* at all.

Answer (score 4):

You should always use accessor methods in public classes rather than public fields, regardless of whether they are final or not (see Item 14 in Effective Java).

When you allow a field to be accessed directly (i.e. is public) you lose the benefit of encapsulation, which means you can't change the representation without changing the API (you break peoples code if you do) and you can't perform any action when the field is accessed.

*Effective Java* provides a really good rule of thumb:

> If a class is accessible outside its package, provide accessor methods, to preserve the flexibility to change the class's internal representation. If a public class exposes its data fields, all hope of changing its representation is lost, as client code can be distributed far and wide.

Basically, it is done this way because it is good design practice to do so. It leaves room to change the implementation of `String` at a later stage without breaking code for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps because length() comes from the [CharSequence interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html). A method is a more sensible abstraction than a variable if its going to have multiple implementations.

Comment: `CharSequence` was introduced in Java 1.4, long after `String` was defined.

Comment: `CharSequence` came along long after the `String` API was defined. However, it's a good point, because if `length` were a field, the `String` class would have to have been retrofitted with a redundant method in order to support an interface (which specifies methods only). Instance fields are not object-oriented, and should not be part of a public API. Objects that use them, like `Point` and arrays are old and inconsistent with later work.

Answer (score 2):

String is using encapsulation to hide its internal details from you. An immutable object is still free to have mutable internal values as long as its externally visible state doesn't change. Length could be lazily computed. I encourage you to take a look as String's source code.

Comment: I don't see how creating a getter method on a supposedly `final` variable provides any encapsulation.

Comment: The final variable `count` is internal implementation that it doesn't (and shouldn't) expose. Furthermore, length() is specified by CharSequence, which String implements.

Comment: If by definition this `final int count` that you speak of is always equal to the return value of `length()`, using a method should provide no benefits and only slow down the system. (until it gets inlined, if it does at all)

Comment: Bug String doesn't define `count`, it's not part of String's definition. The purpose of `length()` is encapsulation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: `CharSequence` only exists since 1.4. The abstraction is a valid reason for why one might want to make this a method, but it doesn't explain why it was done this way in 1.0.

Comment: As Yishai points out above, `CharSequence` was made possible in part because `String.length()` was done this way in 1.0. That's not an accident -- the Java designers knew that exposing methods instead of fields can have those sorts of benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the source code of [String](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build-gate/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) in [Open JDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) it's only a getter.

But as @SteveKuo points out this could differ dependent on the implementation.

Comment: what does `dependent on implementation` means precisely in this case?

Comment: I mean that the implementation does not need to be a getter to be compatible with the API.

Answer (score 1):

In most current jvm implementations a Substring references the char array of the original String for content and it needs start and length fields to define their own content, so the length() method is used as a getter. However this is not the only possible way to implement String.

In a different possible implementation each String could have its own char array and since char arrays already have a length field with the correct length it would be redundant to have one for the String object, since `String.length()` is a method we don't have to do that and can just reference the internal array.length .

These are two possible implementations of String, both with their own good and bad parts and they can replace each other because the length() method hides where the length is stored (internal array or in own field).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would happen if an implementation had a `String` type which simply included a `char[]` and an `int` (for `hashCode`), a `Tailstring` type which derived from `String`, and included a `StartIndex`, a `HeadString` type which derived from string and included a `PartialLength`, and a `SubString` type which derived from `String` and included both?  My guess would be that too much code checks to see if something's type *is* `String` rather than seeing if it's `instanceOf String` for that to work, but it would seem to in some ways offer the best of all possible worlds.

Comment: @supercat code checking for String would be a problem. Then there is a slight performance penalty for virtual calls, the jvm has to find out at runtime if it has to call String.length(), TailString.length(), HeadString.length() or Substring.length() instead of just calling String.length() directly (this makes JIT optimizations harder) - so this can be a performance vs. memory footprint decision.

Comment: Well, obviously Java is what it is, but I wonder what would have been the consequences of having `string` as a compiler-recognized type, whose contents would be encapsulated in a `HeapString`.  Such a thing would have allowed operators like `==` to perform string comparison when used on the `string` type; strings could be converted to `Object`, as with `Integer`, comparison on strings stored as `Object` would test reference equality.