# In Java why is length a method for Strings, while it is a variable for Arrays?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is String.length() a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720220/why-is-string-length-a-method)

If I want to know the length of an array I will have to type the following:

```
array.length
```

Therefore, it is a variable in which is written the length of the array called 'array'.

On Strings the same thing will look like this:

```
string.length()
```

Therefore, it's a method that returns the length of the 'string' variable.

But why did they choose to make those two different, while it basically does the same thing... Is this because of efficiency or why else?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first may be regarded as a property of the object array, but the second is a method accessing the object string. If I'm wrong, I'm waiting for correction.

Comment: "Why is this so" questions are typically not appropriate for this forum. Try (programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's basically history/tradition.  Theoretically, arrays could use `length()` or String could use `length` (which is conceptually a read-only instance field), but they got started off differently.  There is some slight advantage to having array `length` being a pseudo-field in terms of code interpretation/generation, but the advantage, while present at the inception of Java, is largely gone with modern implementations.

Comment: @JBNizet -- `length` is a public field of arrays, yet no one can change it.  It's one odd special case -- a wart on the architecture.

Comment: I forgot about the final keyword for a moment, don't know why :-/

Comment: Add to that size() for collections. length, length(), size() ... arrggh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good question.

arrays are fixed in size and therefore have a public final length field.

strings are implementing the CharSequence interface that have the length() function that needs to be implemented.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I guess I had a mental slip ~)

Comment: Length was never "calculated".  The char array sharing was done invisibly, under the covers, and had no functional implications at the API.

Comment: The CharSequence interface is a very late invention.

Comment: @Hot: true but thats why the string implementation just returns its internal field