# Why Java's String has the method length() rather than property length (like an array?)

Tags: java, string

Java has immutable strings so its initialised size never changes (like size of an array). The question is - if size never changes why Java requires to call a method `length()` rather than property `length` like in an array? Is `length()`

Comment: Because that's the way it was defined.  The bigger question is why arrays have the `length` read-only property, vs a `length()` method, since they are "just objects", like Strings.

Comment: Another identical question is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856327/why-is-string-length-a-method-and-int-length-a-property

Comment: Not every thing must have a plausible reason. The java designers may never have thought about it, or was under the influence of moon phase when he designed one API in a different way.

Comment: @SiyuanRen - Yeah, a lot of decisions went into the design of the original Java.  A bunch of them have been shown to be less than ideal, but that's always going to be the case.

Comment: I feel like you're assuming that getter method is better than property reading. Why is that? It's like unnecessary method wrapping

Comment: @FilipBartuzi read about polymorphism, encapsulation, object-oriented design. Fields are not polymorphic in Java.

Comment: Ok, these are my thoughts now (let me know if I'm wrong @JBNizet): Because `length()` is a getter method we could create our own class (`MyString`) that extends `String` and reuse this method to read length. However I assume that initialiser sets up property of length so subclass (`MyString`) would have access to it without gatherer anyway. Am I right?

Comment: No, you can't because String is final. But, as the answer of Thiago explains, a String is also a CharSequence, and you can get the length of a String by referring to it as a CharSequence. This wouldn't be possible if length was a field.

Comment: @JBNizet - But CharSequence didn't exist when `length()` was decided upon.

Comment: @HotLicks so how did it work before?

Comment: @HotLicks the point is that CharSequence wouldn't be possible if length was a field, and not a method. Methods are what allows polymorphism.

Comment: @JBNizet - There are lots of things that aren't possible in Java, or which are only accomplished by distorting the original design.

Comment: @FilipBartuzi - There was no CharSequence.  It was an afterthought.  A better design would have had String be a subclass of a common class that also had a MutableString subclass or some such, but that didn't happen.

Comment: @HotLicks my point is: the original design (using a method rather than a field) was right: it allows polymorphism and encapsulation, which a field doesn't allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `length()` is defined in `CharSequence` interface, which is implemented by `String`. Interfaces can't define properties in Java. Also, this makes it more interchangeable with other types.

In many methods, you may rely only on `CharSequence` interface instead of a real `String`, then you can use an instance of `CharBuffer`, `Segment`, `String`, `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` in the call site.

See also: [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) documentation.

Comment: `java.lang.String` predates `CharSequence` by many years.